# c# How to use Devexpress XtraReport within a button

Tags: c#, printing, devexpress, xtrareport

I created a XtraReport with Report Wizard. Save the report format. It is working.

I created another page that contains a database table with add, extraction and update buttons. And i have another button to print.

How can i print the saved report format when user click the print button ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the saved report format"?

Comment: When i am using report wizard, i create a report template and save it. I want a button for other users, when they click, they print the data with the saved report template

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://youtu.be/QgYAr39fUTA
Also see: https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/2440/get-started-with-devexpress-reporting/create-a-report-from-a-to-z

Comment: printing is diferent for web and desktop platforms. what platform do you use?

Comment: My project is a windows form program on desktop platform @k0st1x

Answer (score 1):

use the [PrintToolBase.Print](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintToolBase.Print.overloads) method:

```cs
var report = new MyXtraReport1();
report.CreateDocument();
new PrintToolBase(report.PrintingSystem).Print();
```

Comment: How can i use the report template that i created before ?

Comment: your created report is a class that you can instantiate via the "new" operator

Comment: please can you show me how can i do that ? or is there any source to read about it ? Because i can not find any source about that. Thanks for your help

Comment: describe your scenario in greater detail. it would be better if you extract that description as a new thread